# tictaktoe Array bound overflow

Tags: c++, arrays

I am in need of help for this code that i am working on for a assignment. I am have the issue where if i have any X's on the board that is either in the left 2 columns it will display a X in the row above. I used my debugger and it seems that it is trying to access something outside the array bounds, but it shouldnt be. any advice on how to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printTTT(char a[3][3]);
void insertX(/*PASS BY REFERENCE*/);
void insertO(char (&arr)[3][3]);
void checkForWin(/*PASS BY REFERENCE*/); // IGNORE THIS FOR NOW

int main() {

        char TTTarray[3][3] = { { 'X','-','-' },
                                { '-','-','-' },
                                { 'X','-','-' } };

        //char TTTarray[3][3] = { {'-','X','-'},
        //                        {'-','X','-'},
        //                        {'-','-','O'}};

        //char TTTarray[3][3] = { {'-','-','-'},
        //                        {'-','X','-'},
        //                        {'-','O','-'}};

        //char TTTarray[3][3] = { {'X','-','X'},
        //                        {'-','-','-'},
        //                        {'O','-','-'}};

        //char TTTarray[3][3] = { {'X','-','X'},
        //                        {'O','X','-'},
        //                        {'O','-','O'}};


        //insertX(/*CALL*/);
        //OR
        insertO(TTTarray);

        printTTT(TTTarray);

        /*****************
        I have included the declaratoin of the array, initialized to - for each spot.
        The '-' represents an empty position.  You should fill it with either a
        capital 'O' or a capital 'X'. I have also included a number of initialized arrays
        to test; just comment out the ones you don't want for that moment
        *****************/
        return 0;
}

void printTTT(char a[3][3])
{
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                        cout << a[i][j];
                }
cout << endl;
        }
}

void insertX(/*PASS BY REFERENCE*/) {

}

void insertO(char (&arr)[3][3])
{
        int x1x;
        int x1y;
        //int x2x;
        //int x2y;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
                int go = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                        if (arr[i][j] == '-')
                        {
                                x1x = i;
                                x1y = j;
                                // looking for 2 x's for the block lol
                                if (x1x == 0 && go == 0)
                                {
                                        if (arr[x1x][x1y + 1] == 'X' && arr[x1x][x1y + 2] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                        if (arr[x1x][x1y - 1] == 'X' && arr[x1x][x1x + 1] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                        if (arr[x1x][x1y - 1] == 'X' && arr[x1x][x1x - 2] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                }
                                if (x1x == 1 && go == 0)
                                {
                                        if (arr[x1x][x1y + 1] == 'X' && arr[x1x][x1y + 2] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                        if (arr[x1x][x1y - 1] == 'X' && arr[x1x][x1x + 1] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                        if (arr[x1x][x1y - 1] == 'X' && arr[x1x][x1x - 2] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
 }
                                if (x1x == 2 && go == 0)
                                {
                                        if (arr[x1x][x1y + 1] == 'X' && arr[x1x][x1y + 2] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                        if (arr[x1x][x1y - 1] == 'X' && arr[x1x][x1x + 1] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                        if (arr[x1x][x1y - 1] == 'X' && arr[x1x][x1x - 2] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                }




                                if (x1y == 0 && go == 0)
                                {
                                        if (arr[x1x + 1][x1y] == 'X' && arr[x1x + 2][x1y] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                        if (arr[x1x - 1][x1y] == 'X' && arr[x1x + 1][x1x] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                        if (arr[x1x - 1][x1y] == 'X' && arr[x1x - 2][x1x] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                }
                                if (x1y == 1 && go == 0)
                                {
                                        if (arr[x1x + 1][x1y] == 'X' && arr[x1x + 2][x1y] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                        if (arr[x1x - 1][x1y] == 'X' && arr[x1x + 1][x1x] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                        if (arr[x1x - 1][x1y] == 'X' && arr[x1x - 2][x1x] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                }
                                if (x1y == 2 && go == 0)
                                                                                                   181,1-8       83%
 {
                                        if (arr[x1x + 1][x1y] == 'X' && arr[x1x + 2][x1y] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                        if (arr[x1x - 1][x1y] == 'X' && arr[x1x + 1][x1x] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                        }
                                        if (arr[x1x - 1][x1y] == 'X' && arr[x1x - 2][x1x] == 'X')
                                        {
                                                arr[i][j] = 'O';
                                                go = 1;
                                }

                        }
                }

}
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @NathanOliver ive used the debugger and saw that my value for x1y is giving me the issue but i can't see what might be a fix for that

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these lines from your `insertD` function:

```
if (x1x == 0 && go == 0)
{
    if (arr[x1x][x1y + 1] == 'X' && arr[x1x][x1y + 2] == 'X')
```

In this case you have checked that `x1x` is zero, but you haven't checked `x1y`. So in this case you will go out of bounds if `x1y` is non-zero.

A couple of lines below you have

```
if (arr[x1x][x1y - 1] == 'X' && arr[x1x][x1x + 1] == 'X')
```

This will go out of bounds too, when `x1y` *is* zero.

You need to add more checks, or rethink the logic.